# warning: already initialized constant within config/routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I have the following class within `config/routes.rb`. When I deploy the application via Elastic Beanstalk with an `.ebextensions` file including a post-deploy script to start `delayed_job` I receive:

```
...
warning: already initialized constant DistributionSlugConstraint::MATCH_REGEX
warning: previous definition of MATCH_REGEX was here
delayed_job: running [pid 14867]
...
```

Class within `config/routes.rb`.

```
class DistributionSlugConstraint
  MATCH_REGEX = /B[a-zA-Z1-9_]{5}/
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.fullpath =~ MATCH_REGEX
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  constraints(DistributionSlugConstraint) do
    get "/:slug" => "distributions#show", as: :distribution
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of reasons why this error may be happening, but a fix would be to not declare the constant. Not sure it you're using `DistributionSlug::MATCH_REGEX` elsewhere in your code, but if you aren't, you can do:

```
class DistributionSlugConstraint
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.fullpath =~ /B[a-zA-Z1-9_]{5}/
  end
end
```

If you are using it elsewhere in your code you could make it a class method and call that instead of the constant. Another route to go might be to declare it as a configuration in `application.rb`

I've seen this kind of thing pop up when using a multi-threaded app server like `puma`, or in `Sidekiq` jobs. Hard to say more without knowing more about your infrastructure.